# Updating ajax-datatables-rails table with results from custom ajax search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I've got a simple dataTables solution, using ajax-datatables-rails gem. It works great, but I'm now trying to implement a solution where I can update the existing dataTable in place, with results from a separate action, called from a custom search form. In my current code, a part of the controller action looks like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { render json: CasefileDatatable.new(view_context, {:user_id => current_user.id}) }
end
```

(not currently using the `user_id`, just testing passing into the ...Datatable class from the controller)

With `CasefileDatatable` I have the following:

```
def data
    records.map do |record|
      [
          record.county.county_name,
          record.date.strftime("%m/%d/%y"),
          record.case_number,
          record.primary_property_address,
          record.table_json.to_s
      ]
    end
end    


def get_raw_records
    Casefile.all
end
```

The last column, `record.table_json.to_s`, is hidden. It contains content that I need in subsequent processing.

Javascript:

```
var casefileTable = $('#casefiles-table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": $('#casefiles-table').data('source'),
        "stateSave": false,
        "pagingType": 'full_numbers',
        columns: [
            {data: '0'},
            {data: '1'},
            {data: '2'},
            {data: '3'}
        ]
});
```

This all works great. I then went about adding a custom search form, as this model is a little more extensive and requires the ability to search on optional attributes, across several models using joins, etc. So, I have another action that fields this ajax request from the form and then returns json using jbuilder in the first attempt. My strategy was to use the dataTable API to manipulate the existing dataTable directly, and I added the relevant js calls in my form on...ajax:success handler, like this:

```
//this seems to trigger a reset/refresh, so I arrive where I started
$('#casefiles-table').dataTable().fnClearTable();
$('#casefiles-table').dataTable().fnAddData(data);
```

And then these dataTable calls, which did nothing:

```
...
var dt = $('#casefiles-table').DataTable();
dt.clear().draw();
dt.rows.add(data);
dt.draw();
...
```

Then it occurred to me that maybe I could return a different Datatable class, and do all the AR query stuff in my controller, and just pass in the ActiveRecord_Relation object, and then use that in the new, `CasefileSearchDatatableClass`, like this:

Controller action return:

```
  render json: CasefileSearchDatatable.new(view_context, {:query => finder})
```

and then in the `CasefileSearchDatatable` class `get_raw_records`:

```
def get_raw_records
    results = options[:query]
    # following line was just to test passing in the query via options
    # p "search raw records results: #{results.size}"
    results
end
```

This kind of works; the query gets tripped as evidenced by the sql logs and my p statements, but, the data-table is not updated with the results, nor is it cleared; remains totally unchanged.

So, I'm trying to arrive at the best means of updating this table in place, using either one of the above methods or an entirely different approach if necessary. Also, not sure how to best handle paging, assuming the first goal is possible. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This JavaScript code should have worked (with the exception of one extra `draw()`), not sure why it didn't:

```
var dt = $('#casefiles-table').DataTable();
dt.clear();
dt.rows.add(data);
dt.draw();
```

I don't think your approach with a separate Ajax call would work because you have Ajax sourced data with server-side processing enabled (`"serverSide": true`). Therefore after you add custom-filtered data any consequent user action (sorting, next/prev page) will call URL specified by `$('#casefiles-table').data('source')` and will reset your custom-filtered data.

**SOLUTION**

With custom filtering controls, it's recommended to use [ajax.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) property to send custom variables to the server-side script. For example:

```
$('#casefiles-table').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "url":  $('#casefiles-table').data('source'),
    "data": function ( d ) {
        d.extra_search = $('#extra').val();
    }
  }
});
```

Then on the server-side you retrieve values of these custom variables (for example, `params.extra_search`) and adjust your query accordingly.

Comment: ah, so that's why it's getting reset; makes sense. So, using "data":function... approach, I'd still use the same controller action, and move my existing search logic for extracting the parameters, where those form elements are specified within that block? And then I could take the same approach where I pass in the query reference to an ActiveRecord_Relation into the CasefileSearchDatatable instance I'm returning? I think that's what you're proposing? Thanks for the helpful answer; answers the question as to why the table was resetting after, at the very least.

Comment: @wkhatch, I'm not a Ruby expert, so I can only make generic recommendation here. Yes, you need to move your custom search logic into the same controller that handles the data table and adjust your query when those parameters are not empty (add extra `JOIN`, `WHERE` clauses, etc.).

Comment: understood, thanks for the clarification, Gyrocode. I'm trying to understand how, given another form, with several elements and a submit, how that would actually trigger this update within the function(d) block? I can easily get the other form elements val(); no problem there, but, not quite understanding how I'd trigger this block from the containing forms submit action? I can add a listener to the form submit, so I'm wondering if there's some function I call within that listener, on the dataTable itself, that would then cause the search/refresh?

Comment: @wkhatch, you need to use [ajax.reload()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) to trigger another Ajax request, see this [simplistic example](http://jsfiddle.net/wx1odf4k/1/).

Comment: ok, that's what I was looking for. I'll do some refactoring, and hopefully get it working. You'll know the outcome by whether you get the points, or another question... ;-) Thanks again.